# Video goes inside the ground plane (motion tracking)

Tags: tracking

I'm really new to motion tracking in blender, and for whatever reason, the video is only being shown inside of the "Ground" plane.

In the motion tracking tab:

[image]

In the layout tab (Render preview):
[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, does anyone know?

PS: When I render it only the cube and plane show up, but I think this is done in a later stage. (I'm following a tutorial)

Comment: did you press `Numpad 0`?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yes, from what I know the video is only shown in that view.